# Problem when trying to convert .docx files to .pdf

Tags: python, python-os, docx2pdf

I'm trying to create a simple docx to pdf converter and it throws me this problem:

Exception has occurred: com_error
(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Sorry, we couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?\r (C:\Windows\system32\document1.docx)', 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)

```
import os
filesToConvertPath = os.getcwd() + r'\docxFiles'
folderWithPdfFIles = os.getcwd() + r'\pdfFiles'
for i in range(len(os.listdir(filesToConvertPath))):
    convert(os.listdir(filesToConvertPath)[i], folderWithPdfFIles)
```

.py file is in the main folder, with 2 subfolders, docxFiles and pdfFiles

Comment: If you are using office from 2010 onwards, don't waste your time:  You can save as a pdf file directly from Word.

Comment: No, its 2007. Also it is a LOT of files

Comment: Where are you running your script from?   If it is from a cmd prompt, are you cd'ing to the directory and then running or running directly from C:\windows\system32?

Comment: Note that the results from `os.listdir()` can only be interpreted _relative to the path you passed to `os.listdir()`_. Consider doing an `os.chdir(filesToConvertPath)` to make that your current directory so everything is evaluated relative to that location before you start calling `convert()`; if you don't do that, you'll want to use `os.path.join()` on the paths that come back from `listdir` before you try to use them.

Comment: @cup I am running it from the main folder, not cmd prompt, code opened in code editor

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you , your idea worked. I had to chdir() to the folder with docx files, convert them and then chdir() to the folder with pdf files to combine them

Answer (score 0):

Recommend:

1. **Replacing `os.getcwd()` to ensure you get the folder of your `.py` and not of Python**:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from docx2pdf import convert

current_folder = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

filesToConvertPath = os.path.join(current_folder, "docxFiles")
folderWithPdfFIles = os.path.join(current_folder, "pdfFiles")
```

2. (Optional) **Replacing looping over Word docs to providing input and output folder**. `docx2pdf` allows batch converting and outputting using *folders* (as well as single files) ([documentation](https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf#cli)).

Replace:

```
for i in range(len(os.listdir(filesToConvertPath))):
    convert(os.listdir(filesToConvertPath)[i], folderWithPdfFIles)
```

With:

```
convert(filesToConvertPath, folderWithPdfFIles)
```